# Strange TypeError: The function either returned None or ended without a return statement

Tags: python, email, web, flask

I am sending an email to recover user password and when the user clicks on the link he can write a new password. This is the function running in Flask:

```
@app.route("/forgotT/<tokenn>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def reset_password(tokenn):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = s.loads(tokenn, max_age=86400)
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if request.form.get("newpa") != request.form.get("confirmpa"):
            flash("Passwords dont match")
            return render_template("forgotT.html")
        else:
            newpassword=generate_password_hash(request.form.get("newpa"))
            user.password = newpassword
            db.session.commit()
            flash("Password changed")
            return render_template("login.html")
```

Now the problem is that, when I enter the link for the first time and try to change my password i am getting this type error, but if i then enter the link again for the second time and try to change the password, the password changes correctly without any problem. Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your route is accepting 2 methods: **GET** & **POST**.

In the case of **GET**, your *if* statement is *False* and nothing is returned, **raising an error**.

In the case of **POST**, everything works fine since you always return something.

Comment: so should i add a get handler or should i delete that option?

Comment: Also why i'm getting this error when i make a post request? Shouldn't it be when i make the get request?

Comment: Do you want this page being accessible with a get method ? If yes, handle the case of GET, if not, remove it.

Comment: For your second comment, please edit your post with the stacktrace, without that I can not know the problem.